# extract information from hard .log file

Tags: linux, text-processing

I've got a big .log file containing a lot of information and I would like to extract only few of this and put all in different outputs files.

Example of part of the .log file:

```
.....
New Water Solv 104: solv=  1.635

Saved WATERFLAP_REFINED2_SCORED_SOLV_H2O.pdb


Water:   1 AtId: 3021 ResId: 316    OH2n: -8.922    OH2s: -6.900    CRY: -0.640 ENTR: -0.321    SOLV:  0.000    DG:  6.636  CLASS: 1
Water:   2 AtId: 3013 ResId: 308    OH2n: -8.331    OH2s: -7.364    CRY: -0.885 ENTR: -0.321    SOLV:  0.000    DG:  6.453  CLASS: 1
Water:   3 AtId: 3009 ResId: 304    OH2n: -7.424    OH2s: -7.321    CRY:  5.000 ENTR: -0.036    SOLV:  0.577    DG:  5.450  CLASS: 1
Water:   4 AtId: 3064 ResId: 359    OH2n: -9.779    OH2s: -8.778    CRY: -1.187 ENTR: -0.804    SOLV:  0.000    DG:  3.279  CLASS: 1
Water: 103 AtId: 2996 ResId: 291    OH2n: -14.725   OH2s: -10.556   CRY: -1.060 ENTR: -0.607    SOLV:  0.962    DG: -0.849  CLASS: 5
Water: 104 AtId: 3004 ResId: 299    OH2n: -14.237   OH2s: -11.215   CRY: -1.197 ENTR: -0.500    SOLV:  1.635    DG: -1.185  CLASS: 5

Water Network Score Contributions:

Total       OH2n: -731.606  OH2s: -368.197  CRY: -30.908    ENTR: -94.714   DG:  28.882
Average     OH2n: -12.835   OH2s: -6.460    CRY: -0.542 ENTR: -1.662    DG:  0.507
Summary:     28.882 ( -10.345  39.228 )


Saved WATERFLAP_REFINED2_SCORED_OH2s_H2O.pdb

Saved WATERFLAP_REFINED2_SCORED_OH2n_H2O.pdb

Saved WATERFLAP_REFINED2_SCORED_DRY_H2O.pdb

Saved WATERFLAP_REFINED2_SCORED_CRY_H2O.pdb

Saved WATERFLAP_REFINED2_SCORED_ENTROPY_H2O.pdb

Saved WATERFLAP_REFINED2_SCORED_DG_WAT_H2O.pdb

Saved WATERFLAP_REFINED2_SCORED_CLASS_H2O.pdb

Saved WATERFLAP_REFINED2_SCORED_CLASS_COMPLEX.pdb

Saved WATERFLAP_REFINED2_SCORED.PDB

Saved WATERFLAP_REFINED2_SCORED_DG_WAT_H2O_ele.pdb

Saved WATERFLAP_REFINED2_SCORED_CLASS_H2O_ele.pdb

---------------------------
WaterFLAP summary of delta DG between apo and complex

Water: 1 AtId: 2994 ResId: 289  DG_APO: -6.921 DG_COMPLEX: -7.026 DDG: -0.105 CLASS: 3
Water: 2 AtId: 2995 ResId: 290  DG_APO: -1.789 DG_COMPLEX: -2.014 DDG: -0.225 CLASS: 3
Water: 3 AtId: 2996 ResId: 291  DG_APO: -0.841 DG_COMPLEX: -0.849 DDG: -0.008 CLASS: 3
Water: 121 AtId: 3138 ResId: 433    DG_APO:  0.000 DG_COMPLEX:  0.000 DDG:  0.000 CLASS: 3
Water: 122 AtId: 3143 ResId: 438    DG_APO:  0.000 DG_COMPLEX:  0.000 DDG:  0.000 CLASS: 3
Water_USED: 1 AtId: 2994 ResId: 289 OH2n: -15.983   OH2s: -15.953   CRY: -1.934 ENTR: -0.250    DG: -7.026  CLASS: 4
Water_USED: 2 AtId: 2995 ResId: 290 OH2n: -12.808   OH2s: -11.344   CRY: -0.291 ENTR: -0.411    DG: -2.014  CLASS: 4
Water_BOUNDARY: 3 AtId: 2996 ResId: 291 OH2n: -14.725   OH2s: -10.556   CRY: -1.060 ENTR: -0.607    DG: -0.849  CLASS: 5
Water_USED: 4 AtId: 2997 ResId: 292 OH2n: -14.971   OH2s: -14.678   CRY: -2.085 ENTR: -0.375    DG: -4.170  CLASS: 4
Water_BOUNDARY: 122 AtId: 3143 ResId: 438   OH2n:  5.000    OH2s: -0.110    CRY: -0.064 ENTR: -4.875    DG:  0.000  CLASS: 5

Saved WATERFLAP_Delta_DG_CLASS_H2O_ele.pdb

Saved WATERFLAP_Delta_DG_DG_WAT_H2O_ele.pdb

Saved WATERFLAP_Delta_DG_CLASS_H2O.pdb

Saved WATERFLAP_Delta_DG_DG_WAT_H2O.pdb


---------------------------

Apo:        DG:  35.441 DH: -3.791  -TDS:  39.232
Complex:    DG:  28.882 DH: -10.345 -TDS:  39.228

-------------
Net:        DG: -6.559  DH: -6.555  -TDS: -0.004


---------------------------
DG Displaced:   13.760
DDG Perturbed:  6.605
DG Disp-Pert:   7.155

---------------------------

WARNING: Setting ATOM parms from HETATM table
Atm:   CA  Q: 0.08
WARNING: Setting ATOM parms from HETATM table
Atm:   CA  Q: 0.08
....
```

The structure of the file is always the same but the number of rows, ID and numbers could change.

From this I would like to obtained 4 different outputs (maybe using some constant "string" always present as "`Saved WATERFLAP_REFINED2_SCORED_SOLV_H2O.pdb`", "`Water Network Score Contributions`", "`WaterFLAP summary of delta DG between apo and complex`", "`Water Network Score Contributions:`"???)

output1: (between "`Saved WATERFLAP_REFINED2_SCORED_SOLV_H2O.pdb`" and "`Water Network Score Contributions`")

```
Water:   1 AtId: 3021 ResId: 316    OH2n: -8.922    OH2s: -6.900    CRY: -0.640 ENTR: -0.321    SOLV:  0.000    DG:  6.636  CLASS: 1
Water:   2 AtId: 3013 ResId: 308    OH2n: -8.331    OH2s: -7.364    CRY: -0.885 ENTR: -0.321    SOLV:  0.000    DG:  6.453  CLASS: 1
Water:   3 AtId: 3009 ResId: 304    OH2n: -7.424    OH2s: -7.321    CRY:  5.000 ENTR: -0.036    SOLV:  0.577    DG:  5.450  CLASS: 1
Water:   4 AtId: 3064 ResId: 359    OH2n: -9.779    OH2s: -8.778    CRY: -1.187 ENTR: -0.804    SOLV:  0.000    DG:  3.279  CLASS: 1
Water: 103 AtId: 2996 ResId: 291    OH2n: -14.725   OH2s: -10.556   CRY: -1.060 ENTR: -0.607    SOLV:  0.962    DG: -0.849  CLASS: 5
Water: 104 AtId: 3004 ResId: 299    OH2n: -14.237   OH2s: -11.215   CRY: -1.197 ENTR: -0.500    SOLV:  1.635    DG: -1.185  CLASS: 5
```

Output2 (Between "`WaterFLAP summary of delta DG between apo and complex`" and first row starting with `WATER_USED` or `WATER_BOUNDARY`)

```
Water: 1 AtId: 2994 ResId: 289  DG_APO: -6.921 DG_COMPLEX: -7.026 DDG: -0.105 CLASS: 3
Water: 2 AtId: 2995 ResId: 290  DG_APO: -1.789 DG_COMPLEX: -2.014 DDG: -0.225 CLASS: 3
Water: 3 AtId: 2996 ResId: 291  DG_APO: -0.841 DG_COMPLEX: -0.849 DDG: -0.008 CLASS: 3
Water: 121 AtId: 3138 ResId: 433    DG_APO:  0.000 DG_COMPLEX:  0.000 DDG:  0.000 CLASS: 3
Water: 122 AtId: 3143 ResId: 438    DG_APO:  0.000 DG_COMPLEX:  0.000 DDG:  0.000 CLASS: 3
```

Output3 (Starting with row which contains `WATER_USED` or `WATER_BOUNDARY` and finished before `Saved WATERFLAP_Delta_DG_CLASS_H2O_ele.pdb`)

```
Water_USED: 1 AtId: 2994 ResId: 289 OH2n: -15.983   OH2s: -15.953   CRY: -1.934 ENTR: -0.250    DG: -7.026  CLASS: 4
Water_USED: 2 AtId: 2995 ResId: 290 OH2n: -12.808   OH2s: -11.344   CRY: -0.291 ENTR: -0.411    DG: -2.014  CLASS: 4
Water_BOUNDARY: 3 AtId: 2996 ResId: 291 OH2n: -14.725   OH2s: -10.556   CRY: -1.060 ENTR: -0.607    DG: -0.849  CLASS: 5
Water_USED: 4 AtId: 2997 ResId: 292 OH2n: -14.971   OH2s: -14.678   CRY: -2.085 ENTR: -0.375    DG: -4.170  CLASS: 4
Water_BOUNDARY: 122 AtId: 3143 ResId: 438   OH2n:  5.000    OH2s: -0.110    CRY: -0.064 ENTR: -4.875    DG:  0.000  CLASS: 5
```

Output4

```
Apo:        DG:  35.441 DH: -3.791  -TDS:  39.232
Complex:    DG:  28.882 DH: -10.345 -TDS:  39.228
Net:        DG: -6.559  DH: -6.555  -TDS: -0.004
DG Displaced:   13.760
DDG Perturbed:  6.605
DG Disp-Pert:   7.155
```

All Output should be a `.txt file` and the delimiter between columns (defined by "`space`" in the input files) should be `","`  or if it's simpler also `"space"` as in the input.

I have not idea how I can do that. Could someone help me with this hardest challenge please?

Comment: You say `the delimiter between columns (defined by space in the input files) should be ","` but that's not what you show in the expected output - please [edit] your question to show the exact output you expect given the input you provided.

Comment: This should be four separate questions (one per desired output). Or the OP should post his/her most pressing need, and then try to adapt posted Answers accordingly.

Comment: What be the conditions for Output4? Why only 3 lines of WATER_USED/BOUNDARY when there are 5 in your input?

Comment: Have you come across `m4`?  you can set up multiple "diverts" to files and send data into the diverts.  At the end you output the files, or even tie the diverts together into a report.  There is quite a steep learning curve though!

Comment: @RudiC I was wrong, I edited it!

Comment: @EdMorton if read well I wrote that in the input file the delimiter is "space" while in the Output my exptected delimiter should be ",". Now I add also a comment that if it simpler in the output the delimiter should be also "space" as in input

Comment: Yes, I read what you said, my point was that the output you showed wasn't formatted as you said you wanted. commas or spaces or any other characters/strings make no difference for a tool to output - just pick which one you want, state it in the text and use it in the output. Keep it simple for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^Saved WATERFLAP_REFINED2_SCORED_SOLV_H2O.pdb/ { out = "output" 1; next }
/^Water Network Score Contributions/            { out = ""; next }
/^WaterFLAP summary of delta DG/                { out = "output" 2; next }
/^Water_(USED|BOUNDARY)/                        { out = ""; print > ("output" 3) }
/^(Apo|Complex|Net|DD?G)/                       { print > ("output" 4) }
out && NF { print > out }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
```

```
$ head out*
==> output1 <==
Water:   1 AtId: 3021 ResId: 316    OH2n: -8.922    OH2s: -6.900    CRY: -0.640 ENTR: -0.321    SOLV:  0.000    DG:  6.636  CLASS: 1
Water:   2 AtId: 3013 ResId: 308    OH2n: -8.331    OH2s: -7.364    CRY: -0.885 ENTR: -0.321    SOLV:  0.000    DG:  6.453  CLASS: 1
Water:   3 AtId: 3009 ResId: 304    OH2n: -7.424    OH2s: -7.321    CRY:  5.000 ENTR: -0.036    SOLV:  0.577    DG:  5.450  CLASS: 1
Water:   4 AtId: 3064 ResId: 359    OH2n: -9.779    OH2s: -8.778    CRY: -1.187 ENTR: -0.804    SOLV:  0.000    DG:  3.279  CLASS: 1
Water: 103 AtId: 2996 ResId: 291    OH2n: -14.725   OH2s: -10.556   CRY: -1.060 ENTR: -0.607    SOLV:  0.962    DG: -0.849  CLASS: 5
Water: 104 AtId: 3004 ResId: 299    OH2n: -14.237   OH2s: -11.215   CRY: -1.197 ENTR: -0.500    SOLV:  1.635    DG: -1.185  CLASS: 5

==> output2 <==
Water: 1 AtId: 2994 ResId: 289  DG_APO: -6.921 DG_COMPLEX: -7.026 DDG: -0.105 CLASS: 3
Water: 2 AtId: 2995 ResId: 290  DG_APO: -1.789 DG_COMPLEX: -2.014 DDG: -0.225 CLASS: 3
Water: 3 AtId: 2996 ResId: 291  DG_APO: -0.841 DG_COMPLEX: -0.849 DDG: -0.008 CLASS: 3
Water: 121 AtId: 3138 ResId: 433    DG_APO:  0.000 DG_COMPLEX:  0.000 DDG:  0.000 CLASS: 3
Water: 122 AtId: 3143 ResId: 438    DG_APO:  0.000 DG_COMPLEX:  0.000 DDG:  0.000 CLASS: 3

==> output3 <==
Water_USED: 1 AtId: 2994 ResId: 289 OH2n: -15.983   OH2s: -15.953   CRY: -1.934 ENTR: -0.250    DG: -7.026  CLASS: 4
Water_USED: 2 AtId: 2995 ResId: 290 OH2n: -12.808   OH2s: -11.344   CRY: -0.291 ENTR: -0.411    DG: -2.014  CLASS: 4
Water_BOUNDARY: 3 AtId: 2996 ResId: 291 OH2n: -14.725   OH2s: -10.556   CRY: -1.060 ENTR: -0.607    DG: -0.849  CLASS: 5
Water_USED: 4 AtId: 2997 ResId: 292 OH2n: -14.971   OH2s: -14.678   CRY: -2.085 ENTR: -0.375    DG: -4.170  CLASS: 4
Water_BOUNDARY: 122 AtId: 3143 ResId: 438   OH2n:  5.000    OH2s: -0.110    CRY: -0.064 ENTR: -4.875    DG:  0.000  CLASS: 5

==> output4 <==
Apo:        DG:  35.441 DH: -3.791  -TDS:  39.232
Complex:    DG:  28.882 DH: -10.345 -TDS:  39.228
Net:        DG: -6.559  DH: -6.555  -TDS: -0.004
DG Displaced:   13.760
DDG Perturbed:  6.605
DG Disp-Pert:   7.155
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but I saw right now that the output 1 is wrong because the string "Saved WATERFLAP_REFINED2_SCORED_SOLV_H2O.pdb" and "Water Network Score Contributions" occur multiple time in the file, maybe 4 or more. I always need to extract last information, so all the strings between the last "Saved WATERFLAP_REFINED2_SCORED_SOLV_H2O.pdb" and "Water Network Score Contributions" reported in the input. Could you adapt the script for that please?

Comment: If the sample input/output you provided doesn't match your real input/output such that it's not adequate to test a potential solution with then [edit] your question to fix your example. Actually, it'd probably be better if you ask a new, followup question for the case you describe since you already have multiple answers for the original example.

Answer (score 0):

grep "string here" file.log

eg:

grep "Saved WATERFLAP_REFINED2_SCORED_SOLV_H2O.pdb" big.log

If you want line above or below the keyword add

-A NUM for after
-B NUM for before
-C NUM for before and after

If you want it to go to a file, use ">" to output the stdout to a txt file

eg:

grep -A 5 "Saved WATERFLAP_REFINED2_SCORED_SOLV_H2O.pdb" big.log > text.txt